# Хранить таблицу MySQL в памяти и периодически фиксировать изменения и на диске

Tags: mysql, mysqli

MySQL версии 5.7.

Есть таблица innodb на сервере, которая может уместиться целиком в памяти (до 1ГБ).

Ежесекундно 300-1000 раз происходит добавление и/или обновление строк в ней.

Возможно ли настроить работу СУБД в таблицей таким образом, чтобы изменения строк (insert/update) фиксировались в памяти и периодически, например, раз в час/минуту сбрасывались на диск?

Задача оптимизировать производительность, немного "разгрузить" диск.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что стоит взять более подходящее хранилище, вроде Redis

Comment: Современные СУБД по возможности держат в оперативной памяти те данные, которые в неё влезают и которые часто используются. Поэтому не надо ничего делать.

Comment: *Есть таблица innodb на сервере, которая может уместиться целиком в памяти (до 1ГБ). Ежесекундно 300-1000 раз происходит добавление и/или обновление строк в ней.* Это - единственная таблица на сервере (не считая системных/служебных)?

Comment: Эта таблица в БД не единственная. Памяти на сервере достаточно... больше 32гб. innodb_buffer_pool_size установил 90% от общей памяти. То что субд держит в памяти эту таблицу вероятнее всего. Но из-за того что ежесекундно добавляется/обновляется порядка 500-1000 записей, полагаю, что эти данные субд записывает на диск, чтобы они не потерялись при возможном сбое питания. Данные не критичны, поэтому хотелось бы, чтобы они записывались не постоянно, а раз в минуту, например.